# Import errors occurred in sugarCRM

Tags: php, import, sugarcrm

While importing the records in custom modules in sugarcrm we are getting error . please find below snap for reference . [sugarcrm UAT instance import error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAaR8.png)
Error logs :
Fri Oct 27 17:20:29 2023 [4633]: Could not connect to DB server with options  as . port : No such file or directory
Fri Oct 27 17:20:29 2023 [4633]: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NULL FROM config WHERE (category = ?) AND (name = ?) AND ((platform = ?) OR (platform IS NULL)) LIMIT 1' with params ["license", "subscription_checked_at", ""]:
No such file or directory

We have verified basic validations, including data types, field mapping, duplicates, and file size, but the issue still persists. We are now exploring the potential reasons for this issue and seeking solutions for resolution.